# How a object for interface Comparable is created

Tags: java, comparable

How can we create object for an Interface and why is the below code block accepted?

```
public class List<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    E list;
    int size;
    List() {
        list = (E[]) new Comparable[10];
        size = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please ignore the quotation marks around the E list and int size.

Comment: `new Comparable[10]` does **not** create `Comparable` objects directly. It has created an array expected to hold `Comparable` objects. Try `new Comparable(10)` and you'll see the failure you expect

Comment: *"How can we create object for an Interface"* Find or build a class implementing the interface, then create an object of that class.

Comment: *"why is the below code block accepted"* It is not. Fails to compile with error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from E[] to E`

Comment: *"How a object for interface `Comparable` is created"* No object of interface `Comparable` is created in that code. The only object created in that code is an *array* object.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating [Java array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type.

You aren't creating other objects, you are just initializing java array with `new` keyword

> create an array is with the new operator. The next statement in the ArrayDemo program allocates an array with enough memory for 10 integer elements and assigns the array to the anArray variable.
>
> ```
> // create an array of integers
> anArray = new int[10];
> ```